# Markdown to PDF

Tags: c#, .net, markdown

Are there any libraries which can convert Markdown to PDF? Or a complete markdown parser which generates tokens instead of HTML directly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I first generated HTML using MarkdownSharp and then PDF using `https://wkhtmltopdf.org/`.

Any other answer which links to a token based parser or a library which could generate PDF directly will be awarded the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check for LaTeX extensions for your markdown parser, which can easily be converted into PDF. There apparently is for the python-markdown parser. For example, https://github.com/justinvh/Markdown-LaTeX.

It also looks like you can use pandoc to convert markdown to LaTeX:
https://pandoc.org/

Comment: a) The first link add support for latex (an extension to markdown). It does not parse markdown into latex. b) Why would I want to convert markdown to latex with pandoc when it can convert markdown to pdf? Although I was hoping for a .NET parser. I will use wkhtml2pdf otherwise.

Comment: depends which kind of quality you want to control.
- latex provides best control on all format
- you can use markdown2html and convert to pdf always with lower quality.

markdown has lots of extensions, please state more background for your needs